# Module Svelte has no exported member Request Error

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I keep getting no exported member error in Svelte. But the tutorial I followed used Request and got no error but I did. But I'm not sure whats wrong

```
import type { Request } from "@sveltejs/kit"; // <--Error Module '"@sveltejs/kit"' has no exported member 'Request'.ts(2305)

let todos: Todo[] = [];

export const api = (request: Request, todo?: Todo) => {
    let body = {};
    let status = 500;
    switch (request.method.toUpperCase()) {
        case "GET":
            body = todos;
            status = 200;
            break;
        case "POST":
            if(todo){
                todos.push(todo)
            };
            return { 
                status: 303,
                headers: {
                    location:"/"
                }
             };
        case "DELETE":
            todos = todos.filter(todo => todo.uid != request.params.uid)
            status = 200;
            break;
    
        default:
            break;
    }

    return{
        status,
        body
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the SvelteKit type definitions and it seems to just use the browser's `Request` type. Which when using TypeScript is included in the lib file `lib.dom.d.ts`.

(The `"lib"` compiler option of the `tsconfig.json` should include `"DOM"`.)

Comment: This is in my tsconfig.json `"lib": ["es2020", "DOM"],`

Comment: Then you should not need an import to have a `Request` type in scope.

Comment: Well the error is gone but I still got `Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0` I thought they were connected somehow

Comment: @doadoadoa That sounds like your code is expecting a JSON response but the server is sending HTML. That is a different issues entirely.